# XML String How to Add Line Break

Tags: xml

What exactly do I add to this XML to ADD a Line Break that recurs after each returned record?

```
while($ors = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$strXML .= "<set label='".$ors['Fund_Name']."' value='".$ors['Fund_Yield_Percent']."' />";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding a \r\n or a \n at the and of your string, just before the "